# BIND 9 DNS: NS/glue closest delegation used

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nslookup, dig

I have the following example existing delegation:

iio.ne.co.uk NS dns1.iio.ne.co.uk, dns1.iio.ne.co.uk HOST 1.2.3.4

If I add a new delegation:

soho.iio.ne.co.uk NS sohodns.iio.co.uk, sohodns.iio.ne.co.uk HOST 1.2.3.5

and I then get a query for soho.iio.ne.co.uk which delegation will answer the query? .4 or .5?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Such a query would ultimately be answered by the nameservers for the most specific zone matching the query name (the authoritative nameservers).

However, it is worth noting that the delegations in the question could never exist side by side in the same zone, just in case there is any confusion on that point.
Ie, the delegation of `iio.ne.co.uk` would have to be done in its parent zone (`ne.co.uk`?), while the delegation of `soho.iio.ne.co.uk` would have to be done in its parent (`iio.ne.co.uk`).
Also, as part of the lookup process both of the delegations in the question (as well as all delegations leading up to that point) would be returned as referrals and followed step by step, leading the way to the authority.

Comment: I do have both delegations currently in the zone of ne.co.uk. So they do exist side by side now. I did prevously though have the delegation of soho inside a zone of iio.ne.co.uk but that made my servers Authoritative for that Zone which I don't want as the actual zone for iio.ne.co.uk exists on the downstream DNS server on .5 Hope this make sense?